# Need with in pixel of a DIV in percentage with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have boxes being created by PHP. Their width is set to 100% of a container in CSS.  I need to find what is the equivalent in pixel of that box...

HTML

```
<div class="masonry" >
<? while($row = $stmt->fetch()){    ?>

     <div class="item" id="needwidth" >
            <a href="#"><img src="..."></a>
     </div>
   <? } ?>
</div>
```

CSS (masonry will add columns based on available screen width)

```
.item{width: 100%;}
.masonry { column-count: 4;}

@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    .masonry { column-count: 2;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .masonry {column-count: 3; }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .masonry {column-count: 4;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
    .masonry {column-count: 5;  }
}
```

I tried this JS in the header:

```
<script>var width = document.getElementById('needwidth').offsetWidth;</script>
```

and in my HTML, I later test it out with this:

```
<script>document.write(width);</script>
```

but it says:

```
undefined
```

Comment: does element exist when your code runs?

Comment: yes it does ........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use clientWidth to get the value you want. But you have to move your code from header to the end of the page or run the code inside a function called by onLoad event because the DOM must be ready when you try to get the property value.

```
<!-- It may not work -->
<script>alert(document.getElementById('needwidth').clientWidth);</script>
<div class="item" id="needwidth" ></div>
```

...

```
<!-- It works -->
<div class="item" id="needwidth" ></div>
<script>alert(document.getElementById('needwidth').clientWidth);</script>
```

If you can use jQuery in your project. You can use some of the ways described below:

```
$('#needwidth').width();
$('#needwidth').outerWidth();
$('#needwidth').prop('clientWidth');
```

See this JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/nanndoj/gjtkvrsy/3/